# How to avoid multiple window functions in a expression in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want spark to avoid creating two separate window stage, for same window object used twice in my code.

How can I use it once in my code in the following example, and tell spark to do sum and division under single window.

```py
df = df.withColumn("colum_c", 
            f.sum(f.col("colum_a")).over(window) /
            f.sum(f.col("colum_b")).over(window))
```

Example:

```py
days = lambda i: (i - 1) * 86400

window = (
    Window()
    .partitionBy(f.col("account_id"))
    .orderBy(f.col("event_date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
    .rangeBetween(-days(7), 0)
)

df.withColumn(
    "fea_fuel_consumption_ratio_petrol_diesel_01w",
    (
        f.sum(f.col("fea_fuel_consumption_petrol")).over(window)
        / f.sum(f.col("fea_fuel_consumption_diesel")).over(window)
    ),
).show(1000, False)
```

[image: Spark Created Two different window]

Comment: There might be some optimization based on ur specific use case. Could u tell us what window is and sample input/output please.

Comment: Okay adding that

Answer (score 4):

You could use **`collect_list`** over **`only one`** **`window`** and then use *higher order function* **`aggregate`** to get your desired result **`(sum/sum).`**

```
df.show() #sample data

#+----------+--------+--------+----------+
#|account_id|column_a|column_b|event_date|
#+----------+--------+--------+----------+
#|         1|      90|      23| 2019-2-23|
#|         1|      45|      12| 2019-2-28|
#|         1|      80|      38| 2019-3-21|
#|         1|      62|      91| 2019-3-24|
#|         2|      21|      11| 2019-3-29|
#|         2|      57|      29| 2019-1-08|
#|         2|      68|      13| 2019-1-12|
#|         2|      19|      14| 2019-1-14|
#+----------+--------+--------+----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

days = lambda i: i * 86400

window =\
    Window()\
    .partitionBy(f.col("account_id"))\
    .orderBy(f.col("event_date").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))\
    .rangeBetween(-days(7), 0)

df.withColumn("column_c",f.collect_list(f.array("column_a","column_b")).over(window))\
  .withColumn("column_c", f.expr("""aggregate(column_c,0,(acc,x)-> int(x[0])+acc)/\
                               aggregate(column_c,0,(acc,x)-> int(x[1])+acc)""")).show()

#+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+
#|account_id|column_a|column_b|event_date|          column_c|
#+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+
#|         1|      90|      23| 2019-2-23|3.9130434782608696|
#|         1|      45|      12| 2019-2-28| 3.857142857142857|
#|         1|      80|      38| 2019-3-21|2.1052631578947367|
#|         1|      62|      91| 2019-3-24|1.1007751937984496|
#|         2|      57|      29| 2019-1-08|1.9655172413793103|
#|         2|      68|      13| 2019-1-12|2.9761904761904763|
#|         2|      19|      14| 2019-1-14|2.5714285714285716|
#|         2|      21|      11| 2019-3-29|1.9090909090909092|
#+----------+--------+--------+----------+------------------+
```

As you can see in the **`physical plan`**, using this method, you can only see **`1`** **`windowspecdefinition`** or **`specifiedwindowframe`**, hence 1 window used.

`.explain()`

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [account_id#4848L, column_b#4849L, column_a#4850L, event_date#4851, (cast(aggregate(column_c#6838, 0, lambdafunction((cast(lambda x#6846[0] as int) + lambda acc#6845), lambda acc#6845, lambda x#6846, false), lambdafunction(lambda id#6847, lambda id#6847, false)) as double) / cast(aggregate(column_c#6838, 0, lambdafunction((cast(lambda x#6849[1] as int) + lambda acc#6848), lambda acc#6848, lambda x#6849, false), lambdafunction(lambda id#6850, lambda id#6850, false)) as double)) AS column_c#6844]
+- Window [account_id#4848L, column_b#4849L, column_a#4850L, event_date#4851, collect_list(_w1#6857, 0, 0) windowspecdefinition(account_id#4848L, _w0#6856L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -518400, currentrow$())) AS column_c#6838], [account_id#4848L], [_w0#6856L ASC NULLS FIRST]
   +- Sort [account_id#4848L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#6856L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(account_id#4848L, 200), [id=#1554]
         +- *(1) Project [account_id#4848L, column_b#4849L, column_a#4850L, event_date#4851, cast(cast(event_date#4851 as timestamp) as bigint) AS _w0#6856L, array(column_a#4850L, column_b#4849L) AS _w1#6857]
            +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[account_id#4848L,column_b#4849L,column_a#4850L,event_date#4851]
```

**`Instead of:`**(2 windows)

```
df.withColumn("colum_c",f.sum(f.col("column_a")).over(window)\
                              /f.sum(f.col("column_b")).over(window)).show()
```

In this **`physical plan`**, we can see 2 instances of **`windowspecdefinition`** or **`specifiedwindowframe.`** hence 2 windows used.

`.explain()`

```
== Physical Plan ==
Window [account_id#4848L, column_b#4849L, column_a#4850L, event_date#4851, (cast(sum(column_a#4850L) windowspecdefinition(account_id#4848L, _w0#6804L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604800, currentrow$())) as double) / cast(sum(column_b#4849L) windowspecdefinition(account_id#4848L, _w0#6804L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, -604800, currentrow$())) as double)) AS colum_c#6798], [account_id#4848L], [_w0#6804L ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- Sort [account_id#4848L ASC NULLS FIRST, _w0#6804L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(account_id#4848L, 200), [id=#1453]
      +- *(1) Project [account_id#4848L, column_b#4849L, column_a#4850L, event_date#4851, cast(cast(event_date#4851 as timestamp) as bigint) AS _w0#6804L]
         +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[account_id#4848L,column_b#4849L,column_a#4850L,event_date#4851]
```

Comment: If  fea_fuel_consumption_petrol is not an integer, can u show what it looks like (how many decimal places max) n I will update